# Customize datetime field in Rails using simple_form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime, simple-form

I am using Rails 3.2.14, MySQL and simple_form for my application.

I have `notification_time` column field set to `datetime` and I customized it as text field like this in `_create_form.erb`

```
<%= f.input :notification_time, :input_html => { :value => DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M %p")}, :as => :string %>
```

This results to `08/10/2013 - 13:50 PM` on the browser.

I have an `_update_form.erb` with just `<%= f.input :notification_time, :as => :string %>`, and it results to `2013-10-08 13:50:00 -0400`

How to make sure I can get `08/10/2013 - 13:50 PM` when I update the form too??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're never setting how it looks.

In your first block of code, you're doing `DateTime.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M %p")`, but you're never doing that anywhere in your second block of code.

I would assume in your `_update_form.erb` you have a variable that corresponds to the form you're updating.

So let's call that `@form`.

Then you can just do this: `<%= f.input :notification_time, :value => @form.notification_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M %p"), :as => :string %>`... or something of that sort.

Comment: I tried notification_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M %p") but didnt know, I need to do @form.notification_time Learnt something new! Thanks!

Comment: Well aware a lot of time has passed since this was posted, but how would this be different for a 'new' form?  It hits me with `undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass` when I'm using it @jamby...

Comment: @SRack What is the value of the time that you're passing in? Are you just trying to do strftime? It sounds like you're not doing `@form.THE_NAME_OF_THE_TIME_VARIABLE_HERE.strftime...`